# Find transaction

Tags: transactions

I sent a transaction that was to take 10 minutes and it is now been 5 hours. I think don't think the wallet address was correct. Can it be reversed or routed to a different wallet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it). Transactions cannot be cancelled, reversed or altered.

Comment: What wallet did you use? You may be able to RBF it to a different address. It's not a guarantee but incentives the miner to mine the one "routed to a different wallet" as you say.